# How can i scan QR code instead of importing an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am building an application where i want to be able to scan a QR Code and not import an image of the QR code. I want to be able to click a button which will open a camera and which will let me scan the QR Code. I also want it to be able to insert the information on to the input field. Like the name to be auto filled to the input field.

Is there any package of doing so? to scan the QR Code?

Thanks

Comment: if you have a QR code scanner that would be easy

Comment: Is it possible to embed this on web so the mobile / tablet can use its camera?

Comment: there's a library for that why don't you start looking for it.
as example for android https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView

Comment: check this out https://github.com/roladn/laravel-qr-code-login

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a laravel package and i came up with this so far.

https://packagist.org/packages/libern/qr-code-reader

This package seems to do the work. But the docs doesn't have much information. Could someone please explain this bit?

What is ("image_stream") in this case? Is it the same stream to read the QR from mobile camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want scan QR-code right from your front-end application you can use for example, [this library](https://github.com/schmich/instascan). It allows to scan QR-codes using device's camera (webcam on PC/laptop).